# Excel of updating dates within a cell with various formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a current summary tab that is using this current formula

Currently, I have a report that is dated back to 2 weeks
`=COUNTIFS(Industrial!A:A,">9/6/2021",Industrial!A:A,"<9/12/2021",Industrial!F:F,"Sold")`

I am trying to have the dates update now to reflect the new dates below
`=COUNTIFS(East!A:A,">9/13/2021",East!A:A,"<9/19/2021",East!F:F,"Sold")`

The hardest part is all the cells have a slightly different region within the formula and we are trying to update the dates automatically within the report. We want the dates to update for 2 2weeks prior, last week and the current week. The hardest part is the formula is pulling from multiple master sheets and each cell has its on region tagged in.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to follow your question likely because of language barriers. However assuming you are asking how to manage updating dates in the formulas to reflect a new period I would suggest removing the dates from the formulas and instead referencing cells that contain dates You could take for example 9/6/2021 and put it in a cell $B$1 (better yet name it 'startdate' and put 9/12/2021 in cell $B$2 (name it 'enddate'). Then you will need to do a find/replace to update your formulas to reference the two cells (or the names) but you won't need to do that again). The next time you want to update the dates simply update those two cells instead of all the formulas.